# Can I profile my application's access to physical memory?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, memory, virtual-memory, profile

I would like to profile how many times my app accessed specific physical memory addresses.

For example,

```
PFN       |    COUNT
0x000123          3
0x000124          5
...
```

Is there any profiling tool or API which I can use?
I am using Ubuntu 16.04, kernel version: 5.0.5

Comment: *Physical* addresses? Why do you care about physical addresses? They change from one execution to the next and are dependent on what other applications are doing.

Comment: If you attach a debugger, you can have memory watchpoints that can count accesses etc. Also tools like `valgrind` monitor all access to memory, but I don't know if valgrind can count accesses. Note that those will be logical memory addresses, you'll have to translate to physical memory addresses using the page table for your process.

Comment: thanks for all reply. I now know it is hard to get Physical addresses. maybe valgrind and perf would be good solution for me @Gilles

Comment: @dirkt thanks for all reply. I now know it is hard to get Physical addresses. maybe valgrind and perf would be good solution for me